# Shared Server (Laravel + Angular) - Laravel API routes work but get 404 on everything else

Tags: angular, laravel, http-status-code-404, shared-hosting

I've been at this for a little while and can't seem to find the issue.
I have deployed a Laravel application which uses angular on the frontend, all works locally as intended.
Since I have deployed it to a shared hosting service on hostinger, I get a 404 on all routes other then the /api/.
It's like it can't locate the home blade. I have updated the autloader, I have tried several different htaccess's, I have updated all routes to use the new domain, I have updated the env file, all to no success.

I have attached some screenshots below of the set-up. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdeme.jpg)

[public_html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma1OK.jpg)

[htaccess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkfXS.jpg)

[retromize_folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBgPi.jpg)

Comment: did you enable rewrite on your server?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2

Comment: Hostinger say the mod_rewrite is preinstalled and enabled on all their shared servers by default

Comment: okay shit :/ I had a similar issue and that fixed it. Did you run ```php artisan route:clear``` / ```php artisan route:cache```

Comment: I did but I've just run them again on the server just in case but unfortunately, same 404 result

Comment: If you run `php artisan route:list` do you get the correct routes, as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being how the route was setup in my Web API. I was filtering based on the /API which was causing issues. Removing the filter got it working.